# Using "in" or "on" to indicate membership

Tags: prepositions

While reading the definitions of "in" and "on", something puzzled me.

> About "in"
>
> One [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in) says this "***forming a part of something***" and gives
>   examples about it:
>
> He used to be the lead singer ***in a rock band***.
>
> He sings ***in*** ***the church choir***.

---

> About "on"
>
> Another [dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/on) say this "***if someone is on a team, committee, etc.,
>   they are a member of it***" and gives examples:
>
> There are only three directors ***on the board***.
>
> I’m glad to have a player like you ***on our team***.

I think "in" and "on" convey the pretty much the same meaning in both situations. 
How can I choose the right preposition here? Does it depend on the noun following the preposition? I mean when you are using "team" you should use "on" but when using band, you should use "in"

For example, what is the correct preposition in the examples below?

> We have 20 members ***in/on our book club***.
>
> We have new faces ***in/on our clan***. (I used the clan as "a group
>   of people who share an interest or goal")

Comment: Yes, it depends on the noun that follows. *on a committee*, *on a panel* but *in a discussion group*, *in a club*, *in our clan*. There may be some underlying rule but I think it is so nebulous that it is better to learn the right proposition for each word individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can find both the instances where on/in is used. And yes, both can be used. Nevertheless, in my humble opinion, the preposition 'on' is more preferred when the platform is online.

> I have 399 registered people ***on*** my FB page.

But, ...

> I have 23 students ***in*** my group or circle.

So, if the *book club* is online, I'd prefer using ***'on.'***

Again, *both are okay* and can be used but when it's on the Internet or digital devices, *'on'* is what I may prefer.